# Getting precise percentages from a SQL Query in R using the RODBC Connection

Tags: sql, r, rodbc

I am trying to create a function in R using the RODBC package to loop through five tables in a SQL database to find the count of rows for each year for each variable, the % null for each year for each var, and the % missing for each year for each var. I am having trouble creating a single function to give me this accurate output. I created a function that outputs the total count and percent null, but cannot seem to get it to produce an accurate percent missing directly - it seems to be rounding to whole integers, and not consistently rounding up or down.  Below is my code. Any help with this would be much appreciated.

```
PctNull <- sqlQuery(channel, "select 
                [EVENT_YEAR] AS 'YEAR', 
                COUNT(*) AS 'TOTAL',
                (((COUNT(CASE WHEN MOTHER_EDUCATION_TRENDABLE = -1 THEN 1 END))*100)/COUNT(*)) AS 'PctMiss',
                (((COUNT(*) - COUNT(MOTHER_EDUCATION_TRENDABLE))*100)/COUNT(*)) AS 'PctNull'


                from [GA_CMH].[dbo].[BIRTHS]

                GROUP BY [EVENT_YEAR]
                ORDER BY [EVENT_YEAR]")
```

[Here is my output and desired format, however I would like to improve my PctMiss accuracy:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuPdz.png)

Comment: Please show your actual results and desired results. Are you doing integer division? Why not make a reproducible example using built-in data? There are lots of reproducible examples from the package documentation that simulate databases. You can work with those.

Comment: I just added the results. Yes, I am doing integer division.  Could you suggest a built-in dataset? I tried SQLite but am having trouble navigating it/finding it translatable to the project I'm working on.

Comment: Sure, I'd recommend the dataset `USArrests`. They use it in the vignette on about page 4.

Comment: Are you referring to RSQLite?

Comment: `RODBC` https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/vignettes/RODBC.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known SQL Server situation where integer columns if used in expressions must be [converted to decimals](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/returning-percentage-2-summed-values) which you can do so implicitly by using at least one decimal value in your expression or explicitly by using `CAST` or `CONVERT`.

For implicit conversion, multiply your `COUNT()` value by 100.00 (with 2 decimal values) or entire value with 1.00:

```
PctNull <- sqlQuery(channel, 
                    "SELECT [EVENT_YEAR] AS 'YEAR', 
                            COUNT(*) AS 'TOTAL',
                            (((COUNT(CASE WHEN MOTHER_EDUCATION_TRENDABLE = -1 
                                          THEN 1 
                                     END)) * 100.00) / COUNT(*)) AS 'PctMiss',
                            (((COUNT(*) - COUNT(MOTHER_EDUCATION_TRENDABLE)) * 100.00) /  
                               COUNT(*)) AS 'PctNull'
                     FROM [GA_CMH].[dbo].[BIRTHS]
                     GROUP BY [EVENT_YEAR]
                     ORDER BY [EVENT_YEAR]")
```

For explicit conversion, specifically declare the type and precision using `CAST`:

```
(((CAST(COUNT(CASE WHEN MOTHER_EDUCATION_TRENDABLE = -1 
                   THEN 1 
              END)) * 100) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) / COUNT(*))
```

Or `CONVERT`:

```
(((CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2), COUNT(CASE WHEN MOTHER_EDUCATION_TRENDABLE = -1 
                                     THEN 1 
                                END)) * 100)) / COUNT(*))
```